# JaCoCo Code Coverage on Bytecode

Tags: jacoco, gosu

We write code in Gosu programming language (https://gosu-lang.github.io/). when we 'make' the project, we get .class files.

Now would like to know whether is it possible to run JaCoCo on the byte code generated by different compiler / interpreter.

Thanks in advance,
Murali

Answer (score 2):

The core of JaCoCo works at the bytecode level and does not care what the source language was, so you should be able to collect coverage data (.exec files) and generate basic reports.  Depending on how the programming language translates source files to JVM packages/classes, the builtin reporting classes might not be able to find the source files (it expects `packageName.replace('.', '/') + '/' + debugSourceName` to be the location), so you might have to write custom code if you want annotated source files.

Comment: if you are using Gosu as part of the Guidewire product suite there is also an accelerator you can get to run JaCoCo code coverage tools over your codebase.